# Small CPU Emulator (LC3) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lc-3

I wrote a small emulator for fun. Full code @ bottom of post, available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/ianklatzco/lc3/blob/master/lc3.py).

Design choices:

- modeling 16 bit little endian memory — opted for `ctypes` and array-like access via `__getitem__`
- `Enum` library

  - Opcodes - convenient to access: the order of the opcodes in the enum matches the opcode's numeric value when interpreted as an integer
  - Condition flags - convenient to access: named, so I can `self.registers.cond = condition_flags.z`
     where the right hand side is the enum.
- Some classes:

  - CPU (`class lc3`)

    - Registers
    - Memory

---

Questions:

- How could I get started adding unit tests?
- Is there a better choice than using an `IntEnum` for the opcodes?
- How might I organize the code better? In particular, I dislike having `dump_state` (a diagnostic printing function), and all of my instruction implementations (eg `op_and_impl`) right next to each other in the `lc3` class.
- How else might I organize this mapping of opcodes to implementation functions?

```
# first attempt
if opcode == opcodes.op_add:
    self.op_add_impl(instruction)
elif opcode == opcodes.op_and:
    self.op_and_impl(instruction)
elif opcode == opcodes.op_not:
    self.op_not_impl(instruction)
... truncated https://github.com/ianklatzco/lc3/blob/7bace0a30353d4b1d4c720eddca07c1828f7c3e0/lc3.py#L303

# second attempt
opcode_dict = {
    opcodes.op_add: self.op_add_impl,
    opcodes.op_and: self.op_and_impl,
    opcodes.op_not: self.op_not_impl,
... truncated https://github.com/ianklatzco/lc3/blob/67353ebb50367430a7d2921d701ea92aa2f0968e/lc3.py#L304
try:
    opcode_dict[opcode](instruction)
except KeyError:
    raise UnimpError("invalid opcode")
```

- How could I address this inconsistency between accessing GPRs (general purpose registers) and PC, `cond`ition register?

```
class registers():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gprs = (c_int16 * 8)()
        self.pc = (c_uint16)()
        self.cond = (c_uint16)()
# I instantiated the gprs as a ctypes "array" instead of a single c_uint16.
# To access:
 # registers.gprs[0]
    # This is convenient when I need to access a particular register, and I have the index handy from a decoded instruction.
 # registers.pc.value
    # The .value is annoying.
```

---

#### Full code

```
# usage: python3 lc3.py ./second.obj

# This project inspired by https://justinmeiners.github.io/lc3-vm/

# There was a lot of copy-pasting lines of code for things like
# pulling pcoffset9 out of an instruction.
# https://justinmeiners.github.io/lc3-vm/#1:14
# ^ talks about a nice compact way to encode instructions using bitfields and
# c++'s templates.
# i am curious if you could do it with python decorators.

# update: i tried this and it was mostly just an excuse to learn decorators, but it
# isn't the right tool. i am curious how else you might do it.

from ctypes import c_uint16, c_int16
from enum import IntEnum
from struct import unpack
from sys import exit, stdin, stdout, argv
from signal import signal, SIGINT
import lc3disas # in same dir

DEBUG = False

class UnimpError(Exception):
    pass

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("\nbye!")
    exit()

signal(SIGINT, signal_handler)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/32031543/1234621
# you're modeling sign-extend behavior in python, since python has infinite
# bit width.
def sext(value, bits):
    sign_bit = 1 << (bits - 1)
    return (value & (sign_bit - 1)) - (value & sign_bit)

'''
iirc the arch is 16bit little endian.
options: ctypes or just emulate it in pure python.
chose: ctypes
'''
class memory():
    def __init__(self):
        # ctypes has an array type. this is one way to create instances of it.
        self.memory = (c_uint16 * 65536)()

    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        if (arg > 65535) or (arg < 0):
            raise MemoryError("Accessed out valid memory range.")

        return self.memory[arg]

    def __setitem__(self, location, thing_to_write):
        if (location > 65536) or (location < 0):
            raise MemoryError("Accessed out valid memory range.")

        self.memory[int(location)] = thing_to_write

class registers():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gprs = (c_int16 * 8)()
        self.pc = (c_uint16)()
        self.cond = (c_uint16)()

# not actually a class but an enum.
class opcodes(IntEnum):
    op_br = 0
    op_add = 1
    op_ld = 2
    op_st = 3
    op_jsr = 4
    op_and = 5
    op_ldr = 6
    op_str = 7
    op_rti = 8
    op_not = 9
    op_ldi = 10
    op_sti = 11
    op_jmp = 12
    op_res = 13
    op_lea = 14
    op_trap = 15

class condition_flags(IntEnum):
    p = 0
    z = 1
    n = 2

class lc3():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.memory = memory()
        self.registers = registers()
        self.registers.pc.value = 0x3000 # default program starting location
        self.read_program_from_file(filename)

    def read_program_from_file(self,filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            _ = f.read(2) # skip the first two byte which specify where code should be mapped
            c = f.read()  # todo support arbitrary load locations
        for count in range(0,len(c), 2):
            self.memory[0x3000+count/2] = unpack( '>H', c[count:count+2] )[0]

    def update_flags(self, reg):
        if self.registers.gprs[reg] == 0:
            self.registers.cond = condition_flags.z
        if self.registers.gprs[reg] < 0:
            self.registers.cond = condition_flags.n
        if self.registers.gprs[reg] > 0:
            self.registers.cond = condition_flags.p

    def dump_state(self):
        print("\npc: {:04x}".format(self.registers.pc.value))
        print("r0: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[0]), end='')
        print("r1: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[1]), end='')
        print("r2: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[2]), end='')
        print("r3: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[3]), end='')
        print("r4: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[4]), end='')
        print("r5: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[5]), end='')
        print("r6: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[6]), end='')
        print("r7: {:05} ".format(self.registers.gprs[7]))

        print("r0:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[0]).value), end='')
        print("r1:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[1]).value), end='')
        print("r2:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[2]).value), end='')
        print("r3:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[3]).value), end='')
        print("r4:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[4]).value), end='')
        print("r5:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[5]).value), end='')
        print("r6:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[6]).value), end='')
        print("r7:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[7]).value))

        print("cond: {}".format(condition_flags(self.registers.cond.value).name))

    def op_add_impl(self, instruction):
        sr1 = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111
        dr  = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        if ((instruction >> 5) & 0b1) == 0: # reg-reg
            sr2 = instruction & 0b111
            self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.registers.gprs[sr1] + self.registers.gprs[sr2]
        else: # immediate
            imm5 = instruction & 0b11111 
            self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.registers.gprs[sr1] + sext(imm5, 5)
        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_and_impl(self, instruction):
        sr1 = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111
        dr  = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111

        if ((instruction >> 5) & 0b1) == 0: # reg-reg
            sr2 = instruction & 0b111
            self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.registers.gprs[sr1] & self.registers.gprs[sr2]
        else: # immediate
            imm5 = instruction & 0b11111 
            self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.registers.gprs[sr1] & sext(imm5, 5)

        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_not_impl(self, instruction):
        sr  = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111
        dr  = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111

        self.registers.gprs[dr] = ~ (self.registers.gprs[sr])

        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_br_impl(self, instruction):
        n = (instruction >> 11) & 1
        z = (instruction >> 10) & 1
        p = (instruction >> 9) & 1
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff

        if  (n == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.n) or \
            (z == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.z) or \
            (p == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.p):
            self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)

    # also ret
    def op_jmp_impl(self, instruction):
        baser = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111

        self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.gprs[baser]

    def op_jsr_impl(self, instruction):
        # no jsrr?
        if 0x0400 & instruction == 1: raise UnimpError("JSRR is not implemented.")
        pc_offset_11 = instruction & 0x7ff

        self.registers.gprs[7] = self.registers.pc.value
        self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_11, 11)

    def op_ld_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff
        addr = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)
        self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.memory[addr]
        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_ldi_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff
        addr = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)
        self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.memory[ self.memory[addr] ]
        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_ldr_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        baser = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111
        pc_offset_6 = instruction & 0x3f

        addr = self.registers.gprs[baser] + sext(pc_offset_6, 6)
        self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.memory[addr]

        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_lea_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff

        self.registers.gprs[dr] = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)
        self.update_flags(dr)

    def op_st_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff
        addr = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)

        self.memory[addr] = self.registers.gprs[dr]

    def op_sti_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        pc_offset_9 = instruction & 0x1ff
        addr = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)

        self.memory[ self.memory[addr] ] = self.registers.gprs[dr]

    def op_str_impl(self, instruction):
        dr = (instruction >> 9) & 0b111
        baser = (instruction >> 6) & 0b111
        pc_offset_6 = instruction & 0x3f

        addr = self.registers.gprs[baser] + sext(pc_offset_6, 6)
        self.memory[addr] = self.registers.gprs[dr]

    def op_trap_impl(self, instruction):
        trap_vector = instruction & 0xff

        if trap_vector == 0x20: # getc
            c = stdin.buffer.read(1)[0]
            self.registers.gprs[0] = c
            return

        if trap_vector == 0x21: # out
            stdout.buffer.write( bytes( [(self.registers.gprs[0] & 0xff)] ) )
            stdout.buffer.flush()
            return

        if trap_vector == 0x22: # puts
            base_addr = self.registers.gprs[0]
            index = 0

            while (self.memory[base_addr + index]) != 0x00:
                nextchar = self.memory[base_addr + index]
                stdout.buffer.write( bytes( [nextchar] ) )
                index = index + 1

            return

        if trap_vector == 0x25:
            self.dump_state()
            exit()

        raise ValueError("undefined trap vector {}".format(hex(trap_vector)))

    def op_res_impl(self, instruction):
        raise UnimpError("unimplemented opcode")
    def op_rti_impl(self, instruction):
        raise UnimpError("unimplemented opcode")

    def start(self):
        while True:
            # fetch instruction
            instruction = self.memory[self.registers.pc.value]

            # update PC
            self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.pc.value + 1

            # decode opcode
            opcode = instruction >> 12

            if DEBUG:
                print("instruction: {}".format(hex(instruction)))
                print("disassembly: {}".format(lc3disas.single_ins(self.registers.pc.value, instruction)))
                self.dump_state()
                input()

            opcode_dict = \
            {
                opcodes.op_add: self.op_add_impl,
                opcodes.op_and: self.op_and_impl,
                opcodes.op_not: self.op_not_impl,
                opcodes.op_br:  self.op_br_impl,
                opcodes.op_jmp: self.op_jmp_impl,
                opcodes.op_jsr: self.op_jsr_impl,
                opcodes.op_ld:  self.op_ld_impl,
                opcodes.op_ldi: self.op_ldi_impl,
                opcodes.op_ldr: self.op_ldr_impl,
                opcodes.op_lea: self.op_lea_impl,
                opcodes.op_st:  self.op_st_impl,
                opcodes.op_sti: self.op_sti_impl,
                opcodes.op_str: self.op_str_impl,
                opcodes.op_trap:self.op_trap_impl,
                opcodes.op_res: self.op_res_impl,
                opcodes.op_rti: self.op_rti_impl
            }

            try:
                opcode_dict[opcode](instruction)
            except KeyError:
                raise UnimpError("invalid opcode")

##############################################################################

if len(argv) < 2:
    print ("usage: python3 lc3.py code.obj")
    exit(255)
l = lc3(argv[1])
l.start()
```

Comment: Bug: `if 0x0400 & instruction == 1:`  — I don’t see how this could ever be `True`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld alas, I am off-by-one. It's supposed to be 0x0800. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Then it is also supposed to be `== 0x0800`.  In either case, `== 1` is not correct, which was the bug I thought I was bringing to your attention.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really good at Python here, but I'm sharing my ideas.

#### Code style

Do you know there's a coding style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)? It provides a set of guidelines for code styling. I'd like to note some of them here:

- Use CapWords naming convention for your classes. Always begin your class name with a cap letter, so `class opcodes(IntEnum)` becomes `class OpCodes(IntEnum)` etc.
- Put two blank lines between class definitions and module-level function definitions
- Indentation: This is a bad indentation:

  ```
  if  (n == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.n) or \
      (z == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.z) or \
      (p == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.p):
      self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)
  ```

  This is the correct way to indent it:

  ```
  if  (n == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.n) or \
          (z == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.z) or \
          (p == 1 and self.registers.cond == condition_flags.p):
      self.registers.pc.value = self.registers.pc.value + sext(pc_offset_9, 9)
  ```

You can use a tool called [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to find out PEP 8 violations in your code. You may not want all of them - for example, I almost always ignore the line length limit, but this is up to you and it's recommended that you follow all the guidelines unless you have a good reason not to.

#### Repeated and similar code

I'm talking about lines like this:

```
    print("r0:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[0]).value), end='')
    print("r1:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[1]).value), end='')
    print("r2:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[2]).value), end='')
    print("r3:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[3]).value), end='')
    print("r4:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[4]).value), end='')
    print("r5:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[5]).value), end='')
    print("r6:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[6]).value), end='')
    print("r7:  {:04x} ".format(c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[7]).value))
```

This repetition is just unnecessary work. You can replace it with a nice loop:

```
for i in range(8):
    print("r{}:  {:04x} ".format(i, c_uint16(self.registers.gprs[i]).value), end='')
print()
```

And the same for your other code where this pattern occurs

#### Conditional style

Use `elif` if your conditions are intended *not* to overlap:

```
def update_flags(self, reg):
    if self.registers.gprs[reg] == 0:
        self.registers.cond = condition_flags.z
    elif self.registers.gprs[reg] < 0:
        self.registers.cond = condition_flags.n
    elif self.registers.gprs[reg] > 0:
        self.registers.cond = condition_flags.p
```

#### Using exceptions

I see you use `MemoryError` in your memory class for access violation. This is better replaced by `ValueError` or better, `IndexError`, because the one you're currently using is reserved for (host) memory issues, particularly memory allocation failures.

There's also another built-in exception for unimplemented stuff, `NotImplementedError`. You should consider replacing your own `UnimpError` with the built-in one.

Comment: PEP 8 doesn't say to use camelCase for classes: it says to use CapWords ([source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)); they're similar but distinct styles.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! i appreciate it c:

Answer (score 4):

## OpCodes

You are initializing your opcode dictionary inside the while loop for fetching instructions.  It only needs to be initialized once; move it before the while loop.

Your opcodes are a set of numbers between 0 & 15.  You index a dictionary based on these numbers to get the method to call.  Why not use an array, instead of a dictionary; it would be faster and take less memory.

Consider building the opcode array (or dictionary) programmatically:

```
OPCODES = [ 'br', 'add', 'ld', 'st', 'jsr', 'and', 'ldr', 'str',
            'rti', 'not', 'ldi', 'sti', 'jmp', 'res', 'lea', 'trap'  ]

opcodes = [ getattr(self, f"op_{op}_impl") for op in OPCODES ]
```

Note: requires Python 3.6 for the `f"strings"`.  Use `.format()` or `%` with earlier versions.

Note: this eliminates the need for your `class opcodes(IntEnum)`.

Since the `op_XXX_impl` functions are not meant to be called externally, they should named starting with an underscore.

Even better: move initialization of the `opcodes` array into your `lc3` constructor, and store it in the object.  It will help when it comes time to add in tests.

```
self._opcodes = [ getattr(self, f"op_{op}_impl") for op in OPCODES ]
```

---

## Memory

You could use the `array` class for your 16-bit memory; you don’t need to create your own `memory` class:

```
self.memory = array.array('H', [0]*65536)
```

The `'H'` is the type code for 16 bit unsigned values.

Similarly, you code create your registers without a `registers` class.  `'h'` is the type code for 16 bit signed values:

```
self.gprs = array.array('h', [0]*10)
```

This creates 10 register locations, 8 for the "general purpose" registers, and two additional registers: `pc` and `cond`, which you could access as `self.gprs[8]` and `self.gprs[9]`.   We can improve on this, making them more accessible using `@property`:

```
@property
def pc(self):
    return self.gprs[8]

@pc.setter
def pc(self, value):
    self.gprs[8] = value

@property
def cond(self):
    return self.gprs[9]

@cond.setter
def cond(self, value):
    self.gprs[9] = value
```

Then you can use and set `self.pc` and `self.cond` directly.

---

## Instruction Decoding

You repeat a lot of code for decoding instructions. You should write helper functions to extract the required values.   Then you could write like:

```
def op_add_impl(self, instruction):
    dr, src1, src2 = self.decode_dr_sr2imm(instruction)

    self.gprs[dr] = src1 + src2
    self.update_flags(dr)

def op_not_impl(self, instruction):
    dr, src1, _ = self.decode_dr_sr2imm(instruction)

    self.gprs[dr] = ~ src1
    self.update_flags(dr)
```

Since `not` doesn’t use `sr2` or an immediate value, the value returned for `src2` can be ignored by saving it to the `_` variable.

---

## Debug output

Instead of printing to `sys.stdout`, you should learn and use the Python `logging` module, for adding (and removing) debug output from your program.

```
import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOG.debug("100 in hex is %x", 100)
```

In the main program, to enable debug output, use:

```
logging.basicConfig()
LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

---

## Testability

The `start()` method does a lot.  Too much, in fact.  It loops endlessly, reading instructions from memory, advancing the program counter, and dispatching instructions.

Let's break this down a bit.

### Dispatch

You want testability.  How about executing just one instruction?   In fact, you don't need to read the instruction from memory, either.

```
def _execute_instruction(self, instruction):
    opcode = instruction >> 12

    if LOG.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        LOG.debug("instruction: %04x", instruction)
        LOG.debug("disassembly: %s", lc3disas.single_ins(self.pc, instruction))
        self.dump_state()

    try:
        self._opcode[opcode](instruction)
    except KeyError:
        raise NotImplementedError("Invalid opcode")
```

Now you could write a test for an individual instruction.

```
def test_add():
    cpu = lc3()
    cpu.gprs[0] = 22
    cpu._execute_instruction(0x0000)   # gprs[0] = gprs[0] + gprs[0]
    assert cpu.gprs[0] == 44
    assert cpu.cond == condition_flags.p
```

### Single Step

With dispatcher, above, we can now easily write a single stepper:

```
def single_step(self):
    instruction = self.memory[self.pc]
    self.pc += 1
    self._execute_instruction(instruction)
```

And again, you can write tests using single stepping:

```
def test_single_step_add(self):

    cpu = lc3()

    # Setup
    cpu.gprs[0] = -22
    cpu.pc = 0x1234
    cpu.memory[self.pc] = 0x0000

    cpu.single_step()

    assert cpu.gprs[0] == -44
    assert cpu.cond == condition_flags.n
    assert cpu.pc == 0x1235
```

### Running

Using `single_step()`, it becomes easy to write the `start()` method.  But lets make it a little better.

Trap #0x25 is a halt instruction, but it also exits the Python interpreter.  That is a little too Draconian.  If a program ever generates that trap, any test framework will come crashing down as the interpreter exits.  Instead, you should use a flag to indicate whether the CPU is running normally, or if it has been halted.

```
def start(self):

    LOG.debug("Starting")

    self._running = True
    while self._running:
        self.single_step()

    LOG.debug("Halted.")
```

The `op_trap_impl()` function would set `self._running = False` when the Trap #0x25 is executed.

You can now write a test program that runs, and halts, and check the state of memory when it has halted.

### Input / Output

Your LC3 is tied to `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`.  This makes it hard to test; you'd have to intercept the input and output streams when you write your tests.  Or, you could have your LC3 cpu have custom `in` and `out` streams, which default to `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`, but can be replaced with [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textio#io.StringIO), so your test can feed data to the program, and retrieve output for validation.  The Trap #0x20, #0x21 and #0x22 would need to read/write to the requested io streams.

```
class LC3():

    def __init__(self, *, input=sys.stdin, output=sys.stdout):
        self._input = input
        self._output = output

def test_io():
    in = io.StringIO("7\n")             # Input test data
    out = io.StringIO()                 # Capture output to string buffer

    lc3 = LC3(input=in, output=out)
    lc3.read_program_from_file("fibonnaci.obj")
    lc3.start()

    assert out.getvalue() == "13\n"     # 13 is the 7th Fibonacci number
```

Comment: i learned that names with a leading underscore aren't imported when you `from module import *`. https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python#single-underscore-before-a-name-eg-code-class_1

Comment: True, but misleading.   If you `from module import *` this module, it would import the top level names like `signal_handler`, `memory`, `registers`, `opcodes`, and  `lc3`.   The entire `lc3` class is imported, not just a subset of the class.  Please do mark non-public members with a leading underscore.  If you are importing `lc3` into a file of test functions, the test functions will have access to all members of the class whether they start with a leading underscore or not.  You shouldn’t access members with leading underscores from outside, but test functions are allowed to cheat a little.